# Applying high pass filter to streaming websocket data in javascript

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, signal-processing

I'm using socket.io to stream data from a node.js server.  The data is coming in at one packet every 33ms.  I'm putting the data into a chart in real-time and I'd like to apply a digital high-pass filter on it.

I'm trying to figure out how to use [DSP.js](https://github.com/corbanbrook/dsp.js/) to apply an infinite impulse response algorithm on the data - high pass at 1hz - but I'm not really sure how to go about this.

I understand that I would create the filter object using this library (`var filter = IIRFilter(HIGHPASS, 1, 30)`), but as for the applying the filter (`filter.process(signal)`), I'm not sure what the `signal` would be.  When each packet comes in, I add it to an array called `data`.  Would it be on this array? Or would I have to do this for each packet as it comes in?

Comment: Hi, Is your issue resolved? I am using same library and trying to achieve the values till HIGHPASS, but not getting how to do it. If you can share me your code or guide me with this will be a great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an IIR filter, all past samples count in computation of the result for current sample. That's why it is called *infinite* impulse response.

I can see 2 options for your processing.

1. Wait, gather all the samples, finally do the processing before displaying the array `data`
2. Do it **real-time**! Keep in mind that the filtered data must not be mixed with raw data. Otherwise the filtering will be distorted. Create a new array `filtered_data`. Each time a packet comes in, copy it in `data` array, then copy `data` array in `filtered_data` and call `filter.process(filtered_data)`. Finally display `filtered_data`.